# R: Result vector is not showing up in For Loop

Tags: r, for-loop

OK, so I am new to R, but I've had some pretty good success so far - I am running a statistical test between corresponding rows of two dataframes (well, one is just a string of values since it has just one column). I wish to use the following For-Loop:

```
zvalues = NULL
zvalues = numeric(0)
for(i in seq(nrow(geneexpx))){
  zvalues[i] <- try(unname((geneexpx[i]-rowMeans(geneexpy[i,])) / rowSds(geneexpy[i,])))
}
```

The problem is, the resultant zvalues numeric is empty. I have no idea why. I can run the same function for a single row and it works fine. For instance:

```
s = unname(geneexpx[4]-rowMeans(geneexpy[4,])) / rowSds(geneexpy[4,])
s
[1] -2.431277e+156
```

Please let me know if you have any ideas as to what might be the problem.

EDIT:
head of geneexpx:

```
c(1.501400411, -0.818584726, -0.455614921, -0.138022494, -1.213938495, -0.536465133)
```

geneexpy is very large, but each column is similar to geneexpx above.

Comment: You can probably vectorize this whole operation.  Please add `dput(head(geneexpx))` to the post and also show the desired result

Comment: @RichardScriven I hope the added information helps. As for the desired result, it would simply be a vector wherein the observation number (row) matches the rows utilized in the original calculation. The basic calculation that I wish to compute for each row in plain english is: (Geneexpx(row1) - Averagevalue(Geneexpy(row1)))/Standarddeviation(geneexpy(row1))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple things going on here. First, you need to define `zvalues` as a vector. Second, `rowMeans` and `rowSds` are operations on matrices, not vectors. By selecting `greneecxpy[i, ]` you are selecting the `i`th row of the matrix, which will be a vector.

You did not provide `geneexpy` so I made one up:

```
zvalues = rep(NA, length(geneexpx))
geneexpy <- matrix(runif(60), nrow = 6)
for(i in seq_along(geneexpx)){
  zvalues[i] <- (geneexpx[i] - mean(geneexpy[i,])) / sd(geneexpy[i,])
}

> zvalues
[1]  3.772994 -4.283168 -2.812811 -2.074548 -5.649359 -4.323920
```